# lm in drm function returning 0 non-na cases error

Tags: r

A little new to using R & stackoverflow but feel free to let me know if my question is vague/silly

So I'm try to use the drm() function in R like thus

```
demo=structure(list(X = c(-5, -5.5, -6, -6.5, -7, -7.5, -8, -8.5, -9, -9.5), 
Y1 = c(68.8, 78.7, 74.7, 55.6, 34.2, 19.9, 9.7, 17.2, 10.1, 3.3), Y2 = 
c(73.5, 74, 71.1, 48.9, 43.4, 28, 15, 7.9, 12.7, 21.2)),.Names = c("X","Y1", 
"Y2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

demo1 <- reshape2::melt(demo,id.vars = "X") 

demo.LL.4 <- drm(data = demo1,value~X,fct=LL.4(),na.action = na.omit)
```

However this error is thrown for the line where I call drm()

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 0 (non-NA) cases
```

I  checked the values of my list after using reshape::melt, and none were shown as "NA". I also call na.action = na.omit in my drm function. Not sure what else could be possibly causing this error.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Instead, I get `Error in drm(data = demo1, value ~ X, fct = LL.4(), na.action = na.omit) : 
  Cluster not specified. Use e.g. y ~ x + cluster(id)`.

Comment: @Lyngbakr
Weird. You're right in that when trying to reproduce the error it doesn't come up, but I know this line is the one causing the error since my print statements stop working right before this line. All the other code before these lines are just library declarations and code to access the shinyServer.